# Flask-SQLAlchemy Numeric Type

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I’m making a Flask-SqlAlchemy app. In one model I want to store geo code data as a lat/long.

From reading other posts, I should use Numeric not Float.

The documentation for type Numeric lists several arguments available:

```
precision=None, asdecimal=False, decimal_return_scale=None
```

So I tried adding a column as

```
db.Column(db.Numeric, precision=8, asdecimal=False, decimal_return_scale=None) — as the equivalent of DECIMAL(10,8)
```

Which returned an error of:

```
 "Unknown arguments passed to Column: " + repr(list(kwargs)))
```

sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Unknown arguments passed to Column: ['asdecimal', 'decimal_return_scale', 'precision']

If I use db.Column(db.Numeric), I’m able to create the tables and write to it.

Would someone explain to me if there is a syntax error in what I passed here:
db.Column(db.Numeric, precision=8, asdecimal=False, decimal_return_scale=None) — as the equivalent of DECIMAL(10,8)

What is the proper way to utilize/define a Numeric type column.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should add the extra arguments to db.Numeric, and not to db.Column:

```
db.Column(db.Numeric(precision=8, asdecimal=False, decimal_return_scale=None))
```

Answer (score 32):

You can also do

```
db.Column(db.Numeric(10,2))
```

Where the first element is the quantity of integer places and the second argument represents the amount of decimal places.